# Nativescript - Use an Android library in NativeScript for Angular using Java apis

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I have to use the native Android/iOS Estimote SDKs in my Nativescript app. The Nativescript app is based on Angular/Typescript.

Also, I require the use of a lot of the advanced functionalities that the native Estimote SDK provides, rather than the simple plugins available for {N} to search and range for beacons.

I would like to know the process to follow to be able to to integrate these SDK classes seamlessly into my app.

Comment: Downvoted for the displayed lack of effort in any research.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation at http://docs.nativescript.org/  specifically the section on plugins; http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins

In addition there are multiple blogs out there (like mine) http://fluentreports.com/blog which have many in-depth articles on creating plugins.